# Changes in MSAccess VBA coding

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset, ms-access-2016

I have been coding in MSAccess since the Win95 days. Over the years, these apps have been upgraded to the latest versions of MSAccess. I am guessing that the change occurred sometime after Access 2003.

I am sure that this is a trivial question, but I can't seem to find the answer in the documentation online.

In the old days, my Modules would look like this:

```
    Option Compare Database

    Private Sub PrintReports_Click()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Classes", dbOpenDynaset)
...
```

Where Classes is usually a table or query in my database. This continues to work in older databases that have been converted to the latest version.

When I try to create a new database using the above code, I get error 13, type mismatch error, with no explanation of what is wrong and how to fix it.

So 2 questions:
Why does it work on old databases but not newly created ones, and what is the correct way to open and refer to my tables in my VBA code?

Thanks for your help,
Dan

Comment: What happens if you declare the recordset like this? `Dim rs As DAO.Recordset`

Comment: Which line of code receives the error?  Please provide more details.

Comment: The line Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Classes", dbOpenDynaset) causes the error

Answer (score 0):

Try to check "References", is it missing anything 
Also Declare db as follows

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
```

Comment: I had already changed the line as you recommended. No change. Where are the "Rreferences" that I should check?

Comment: I made the change as suggested by HansUp Dim rs As DAO.Recordset. It seemed to fix the problem. The question remains, though, why do I need it on new instances of MSAccess and not on old ones. Is there a switch I need to set?

Comment: You can find the reference under Tools -> Reference.

Comment: If you have 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library' enabled under reference, it will conflict between DAO RecordSet and ADODB RecordSet, so the RecordSet must declare with correct namesapce.